# Can how can input text and a video URL and have it written to plist on server?

Tags: php, post, plist

I have an iPhone app that uses a plist to display a headline, video thumbnail, and a url. I have to manually go in and edit the plist on my server now to update the app. How can I programmatically enter the data into a field and have it saved in the plist with php?